# Adding Column to bottom appbar makes it take full screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a bottom app bar with two icons. I would like to add text below the icons, so I figured I would wrap my iconbuttons in a column. When I do this it causes the bottom appbar to take up the entire screen. How can I fix this? Here is the code that causes the issue. It works as expected without the columns.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.blueGrey,
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.note_add),
              color: Colors.white,
              // tooltip: 'Add Note',
              onPressed: () => _startAddNewNote(context),
            ),
            Text('Add Note'),
          ],
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.image),
              color: Colors.white,
              // tooltip: 'Open Image Clue',
              onPressed: () => _startShowImageClue(context),
            ),
            Text('Open Image Clue'),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Before I add the column.

[image: without column]

This is what the column does to the screen.

[image: with column]

Comment: try setting column main axis size to min

Comment: Yeah that's working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the size of `Column` to `MainAxisSize.min` will do the work

```
Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.note_add),
          color: Colors.white,
          // tooltip: 'Add Note',
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        Text('Add Note'),
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.image),
          color: Colors.white,
          // tooltip: 'Open Image Clue',
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        Text('Open Image Clue'),
      ],
    ),
```

And also there is pre-built widget for making BottomNavigationBarItem, you can use it like

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.image),
          color: Colors.white,
          // tooltip: 'Open Image Clue',
          onPressed: () {},
        ),label:"Open Image Clue",
)
```

Suggesting to use this, because it has some text scaling implementations